# How to use onkeyup event multiple times on same input field in jquery?

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

I am working on form where i want to make some calculations. i am using jquery for this.Below is html code and jquery function for the same.

```
function sum(param,id) 
        {
            var daysWork = document.getElementById('days_work_'+id).value;
            var rateReceived = document.getElementById('rateReceived_'+id).value;
            var percPaid = document.getElementById('perc_paid_'+id).value;
            var paidFrmUk = document.getElementById('paidFrmUk_'+id).value;
            var paidFrmIndia =  document.getElementById('paid_from_india_'+id).value;
            var remaining =  document.getElementById('remaining_'+id).value;


            var totalDisplay = rateReceived * daysWork;
            var total = totalDisplay.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('total_'+id).value = total;   

            var toBePaidDisplay = (totalDisplay * percPaid)/100;
            var toBePaid = toBePaidDisplay.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('tobe_paid_'+id).value = toBePaid;

            var paidFrmIndiaDisplay = toBePaid - paidFrmUk;
            var paidFrmIndia = paidFrmIndiaDisplay.toFixed(2);
            var paidFrmIndia = document.getElementById('paid_from_india_'+id).value = paidFrmIndia;

            var addUkIndiaSal = Number(paidFrmIndia) + Number(paidFrmUk);
            var remainingDisplay = toBePaid - addUkIndiaSal;    
            var remaining = remainingDisplay.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('remaining_'+id).value = remaining;

        }



<td><?php echo $RATE_RECEIVED;?></td>
<td><?php echo $CURRENCY_CODE;?></td>   
<td><?php echo $PERC_PAID;?></td>    
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="sum(this,<?php echo $srNo;?>)"   id="days_work_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo $DAYS_WORKED;?>" /></td> 
<td><input type="text"  id="total_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo $TOTAL;?>"  /></td> 
    <td align="center"><input type="text"    id="tobe_paid_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo $PER_TO_BE_PAID; ?>"  /></td> 
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="sum(this,<?php echo $srNo;?>)"  id="paidFrmUk_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo$SAL_PAY_FRM_UK;?>" /></td>            
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="sum(this,<?php echo $srNo;?>)"  id="paid_from_india_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo $SAL_PAY_FRM_INDIA;?>"  /></td> 
<td><input type="text" onkeyup="sum(this,<?php echo $srNo;?>)"   id="remaining_<?php echo $srNo;?>"  value="<?php echo$REMAINING;?>"  /></td>
```

My code is working fine as per my function. but i have some other conditions that i can't able to done with this code.

As you can see last 3 inputs in `td` paidFrmUk_, paid_from_india_, remaining_ .
My calculation is like **paidFrmIndia = = toBePaid - paidFrmUk;**

> its working. but if i want to edit  paidFrmUk after calculation it
>   wont allow me to edit that input box. what is the solution for this.
>   to edit input box once calculated by function.

Comment: This is native js, not jquery.  Can you extrapolate on why it won't let you edit that input box - what exactly happens, an error?  No text appears?

Comment: its not showing error it shows only calculated value in input box . if i force to backspace it wont allow me

Comment: It's because you run the sum again onkeyup so as none of your other inputs change, it re-inserts the answer